# system settings won't start

Tags: unity

When I run `unity-control-center` from the terminal, I get:

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

(unity-control-center:21776): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'unity-control-center' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length erro'.
  (Details: serial 227 error_code 16 request_code 155 (GLX) minor_code 1)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I'm running NVIDIA graphics drivers, if that helps:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

your case is similar to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1291397) bug report

As I can see it's bumblebee related. Are you using it?

Comment: I don't have any packages named `bumblebee*` installed, so probably not.